# Export to excel in php not working correctly in all machines

Tags: php, mysql, excel, mime-types

I am trying to export data from database to the excel using php. But its importing correctly and opens the file perfectly. But in few machines and android mobiles its not working at all

Its showing me error of invalid extension.

Here is the code I am using

```
 $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT Distinct a.*,b.* FROM OrderCalculation a right join  crm_order b on a.orderid = b.orderno");
 $file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
//for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
//echo mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i) . "\t";
//}
//print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }

        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the full error message and where you see it. I would also recommend looking into something like [PHPSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you want to create proper Excel-spreadsheets instead of renaming a csv-file as xls (which are not the same thing).

Comment: Do these other devices have the faintest idea what a TSV file is with an `xls` extension?

Comment: You are sending a tab delimited text file, but say it is an xls file. The built-in defensive mechanisms kick-in and either warn or completely block the file from being opened. This behaviour cannot be controlled from the server - apart from generating true excel files or setting the mime type to csv.

Comment: PS I dont see a `$filename` being defined anywhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly Its defined. I just show you the main code which export data to excel.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually creating an Excel doc here, you're creating a CSV with tab delimiters.

So you have 2 choices: You can replace your headers for content type / file name with the following:

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
```

Or you can look into actually creating a proper Excel file - however this is not native functionality in PHP and requires either some very specific knowledge, or use of a third party library. I have had great success in the past using PHPExcel (Which a quick Google tells me is now PHPSpreadSheet).